# Unable to handle subfolders in Termux

Tags: termux

I'm trying to run a program which has its own directory. Termux doesn't allow creating the directory nor accessing the folder (`permission denied` error) after moving it to the Termux home directory with a root file explorer app. Also with p7zip (command line port of 7-Zip) I can't create a new directory with `7z x -o <folder name> <archive name>`, I can only extract to the Termux home folder.

[Termux FAQ has a page for the error](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_do_I_keep_getting_.27permission_denied.27_when_trying_to_launch_a_script.3F), but the `chmod` command results in `operation not permitted`. I wonder if this issue is related to the differences in Linux distributions and Android:

> Why do I keep getting 'No such file or directory' when trying to
>   execute binary (it's file exists) ?
>
> This happens when you are executing binary compiled for Linux
>   distribution, e.g. Ubuntu or Arch Linux. This is caused by ABI
>   difference between GNU libc and Bionic libc.
>
> Create a proper chroot (proot) environment and try to execute binary
>   from it.

Comment: Which directory you are trying to create with Termux and to which directory you are trying to extract the archive? May I know the exact location? Did you try that with root or without root? And yes, Termux environment is different than that of standard Linux distros. If the p7zip binary is of different architecture or a dynamic binary compiled for Linux linker and Linux libc, that won't work with Android linker and Android libc.

Comment: `ASF-linux-arm`, [ArchiSteamFarm V3.4.1.7](https://github.com/JustArchiNET/ArchiSteamFarm/releases/tag/3.4.1.7) specifically. Unzip (ships with Termux) can't open the archive at all. I tried creating a subfolder inside the Termux home directory, `7z x -o <folder name> <archive name>` command in p7zip.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: My phone is rooted but I haven't issues Termux root rights, I don't yet know how this works.

Comment: Any status updates?

Comment: @iBug: Sorry for the delay, I'll return to the topic after I've reinstalled LineageOS. I get some unknown reboots after installing a major version on top of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the permission or owner has messed up.

Go find a folder where Termux operates normally, and run `ls -ln` to get the UID and GID of Termux (they should be the same, on the 3rd and 4th column of `ls -ln`). Then switch to root with `su` or `tsu` and change the owner of the problematic directory to Termux like this:

```
chown -R 10001.10001 path/to/dir
```

where `10001` should be replaced with the UID of Termux. Then you should be good to go.

Comment: Sorry, I don't necessarily have time to test this before the holidays are over. Your answer looks promising.